# acf_form output of a specific repeater row

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In acf there is a repeater field (let's call it myrepeater) inside of which there are many other fields. In the front end I display the acf form for adding/editing.

```
acf_form([
'field_groups' => [2642],
'post_id' => 'user_' . $current_user_id,
'uploader' => 'basic'
]);
```

The page shows the entire list of completed repeaters. How, for example, when editing, display a form only with repeater id=2 (in html it `<tr class="acf-row" data-id="row-2">`) and save it, not all at once.

```
-myrepeater (1)
 --field 1
 --field 2
 ...

-myrepeater (2) <--
 --field 1
 --field 2
 ...
```

Also when adding, how to show the adding form only, without the added information?